# Java Constructor requiring a condition that relies on another constructor that relies on the first constructor. (Snake biting its tail)

Tags: java, jtextpane

Basically I have a constructor that relies on another constructor which relies on the first constructor. This makes coding this pretty weird.

Here is the problematic code right here:

```
JTextPane textpane = new JTextPane(document);
StyledDocument document = textpane.getStyledDocument();
```

This creates a JTextPane which uses the StyledDocument constructor that then uses JTextPane.

Any help please and thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you have some nasty coupling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't even compile, you are using `document` before you declare it?

why not just do this

```
StyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument(); // or whatever implementation you wish to use
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(document);
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I would do (in the generic sense).  You have to have a document to pass to the JTextPane so if you haven't created one yet you can't pass it in then get it out again...  This would be the same in any OO language.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused, the following code is not a constructor, it is an [accessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessor):

```
StyledDocument document = textpane.getStyledDocument();
```

The object returned is the exact object passed into the constructor for the `JTextPane` via:

```
JTextPane textpane = new JTextPane(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to you can do

```
JTextPane textpane = new JTextPane(new StyledDocument());
StyledDocument document = textpane.getStyledDocument();
```

But hhafez's answer is the more correct way to do it.